# How do I check if a record exists in Flow Builder?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, conditional

I have an autolaunched flow to create a record with particular field values, unless a record with the same values already exists. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/179601/72259) offers a method for interactive flows. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/254056) says headless flows can do the job, but doesn't explain how.

Get Records successfully finds the record if it exists, but errors out if it doesn't.

Comment: How are you setting up your "Get Records"? You should be able to store a null value if no records are returned and then check if that variable is null to confirm if it exists or not.

Comment: you can also get the count of records returned and assign that to a variable for testing > 0

Comment: @KrisGoncalves thanks, using "Manually assign variables (advanced)" allows the null to be stored instead of exiting. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @cropredy I haven't found that option. Do you know where it is?

Comment: example of `equals count` : https://jenwlee.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/flowcollectionwithcount.gif

Comment: @cropredy thanks, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5

Scroll down on the get record screen and select "Manually assign variables (advanced)". There should be an option at the bottom to specify setting the variable to null when no records are returned. Now, you can add a decision to check if this variable is null.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce now recommend using Automatic Output handling. See https://unofficialsf.com/automatic-handling-null/
Automatically store all fields then check for the return reference being null.